# Javascript screen size If Else Statement

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<title>Introduction Process</title>
</head>

<?PHP
$window_width=0;

$window_width= '<script>window.screen.availWidth</script>';

if $window_width <= 500 {
    $Link = "SignUp.php";
}
else{
    $Link = "1stPage.php";
}
?>

<Body>
<center><img src="Alex.png" alt="" align="middle"></center>
<center><div>Hello, I am Alex. I am here to walk you through an 11 question quiz which will help calculate your resilience level.</div></center>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION =<?PHP echo $Link; ?>>

<center><INPUT TYPE = "Submit" class=myButton Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Start"></center>
</FORM>


</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to test for the size of a screen so i know whither or not to send them on to my mobile website or to a full sized website, I am getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$window_width' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in C:\wamp64\www\IntroductionProcess.php on line 12"

Comment: Well for one thing that's now how you write an `if` statement. And for another, ***JavaScript DOES NOT RUN on the server!***

Comment: You don't need PHP for this. You can simply use HTML. Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should research how to write JavaScript `if` statements. As to how to get the screen size, `screen.height` and `screen.width` should give you the screen dimensions, using only JavaScript. Within 2 minutes of searching, I found your answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window). Please do more researching next time you have a problem instead of instantly asking a question.